# Logic for ifelse condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make a logic to check multiple conditions without using if else condition numbers of time.

I have 4 variables and i have to check whether it is empty or not. 
if one of the variable is blank than want to do something.

I have function like this..

```
function searchResult($genre, $subject, $type, $grade){
 // checking conditions here
}
```

please suggest me simple method.

Comment: do you need to know which variable is blank? If so then you'll need to check each value independently otherwise you can use a logical `&&` operator to and together the checks/

Comment: you must have to use if condition weather its empty or not !!

Comment: you can use switch case

Comment: how. should i use this

Comment: @AmitChouhan its so funny

Comment: Define "empty". Does that mean empty string? `0`? `false`? `== false`? Any/all of the above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `func_get_args`, `array_filter` and `func_num_args` as well:

```
function searchResult($genre, $subject, $type, $grade){
    if (count(array_filter(func_get_args())) < func_num_args()) {
        echo 'One or many arguments are empty.. do something';
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the array_filter function:

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE ([see converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchResult($genre, $subject, $type, $grade){

 if((!empty($genre))  &&  (!empty($subject)) && (!empty($type)) )
 { 
     echo "not empty";
 } 
 else
 {
      echo "empty";
 }

}
```

Comment: This would not work. Every variable has to be empty for the code the execute.

Comment: this would work as he's checking the result is `!empty()` reads as *not* empty

Comment: Use superfluous `()` much? :P